# Не работает метод map, ошибка React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Помогите решить проблему.

Пытаюсь вывести на экран элементы объекта `state`:

```
class App extends Component {    
  state = {
    arr: ['one', 'two', 'three']
  }    
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      { this.state.arr.map((item, index) => {
        <div></div>
      })}
    </div>
  )}
}

export default App;
```

а получаю ошибку:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an 
expression  no-unused-expressions. 
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли добавить `return`, поскольку [метод map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) должен *вернуть* новый массив:

```
{this.state.arr.map((item, index) => {
  return <div></div>
})}

// или поменять фигурные скобки на круглые

{this.state.arr.map((item, index) => (
  <div></div>
))}

// или отказаться от скобок вообще

{this.state.arr.map((item, index) => <div></div>)}
```